# Div content scroll and auto height

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want to have content to be scrollable if needed but also smaller in height if there is less content inside. Second panel should shrink in size since there is less content (open full page snippet). Without adjusting '.parent' css.

```css
.parent {

}

#panel2 {
  left: 350px;
}

.apvr-presentation-panel-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ede;
  max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.apvr-presentation-panel-opened {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.apvr-presentation-panel {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.apvr-presentation-content-wrap {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.apvr-presentation-content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.apvr-presentation-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  margin: 3px;
}

.apvr-presentation-desc {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="apvr-presentation-panel-wrap">
    <div class="apvr-presentation-panel">
      <div class="apvr-presentation-content-wrap">
        <div class="apvr-presentation-content">
          <p class="apvr-presentation-title">Class aptent</p>
          <p class="apvr-presentation-desc">Mauris et sapien. Quisque risus. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi. Nam vestibulum viverra diam. Nullam eros ipsum, rutrum ut, ultricies sed, congue sed, est. Pellentesque porttitor. Donec dictum urna eu mi. Maecenas in lorem. Vestibulum in ipsum. Praesent
            ac nunc. Donec vitae lectus. Etiam commodo velit ut mi. Duis egestas, quam faucibus interdum tincidunt, enim sem tincidunt tellus, Mauris et sapien. Quisque risus. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi. Nam vestibulum viverra diam. Nullam eros ipsum, rutrum
            ut, ultricies sed, congue sed, est. Pellentesque porttitor. Donec dictum urna eu mi. Maecenas in lorem. Vestibulum in ipsum. Praesent ac nunc. Donec vitae lectus. Etiam commodo velit ut mi. Duis egestas, quam faucibus interdum tincidunt, enim
            sem tincidunt tellus, sed condimentum tellus tortor ut mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce aliquet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
            inceptos himenaeos. Aliquam sollicitudin, nisi egestas scelerisque pretium, odio enim sodales metus, venenatis vulputate arcu quam eget purus. Fusce convallis mattis nunc. Fusce non nunc. Maecenas nec tellus a mi ornare auctor. Proin magna
            nunc, congue ut, dapibus eu, placerat vitae, erat. Nam egestas pretium mauris. Cras posuere, est nec egestas scelerisque, tellus justo scelerisque nisi, at consequat ante dolor eget diam. Phasellus pharetra, lectus vel molestie tincidunt,
            orci tellus dapibus odio, vel semper lacus tortor vitae metus. Vestibulum accumsan enim nec ipsum. Nunc cursus sapien. Etiam fermentum luctus arcu. Curabitur vitae velit eget nisl ornare sollicitudin. Etiam vitae erat. Integer sapien. Vivamus
            non massa non est consequat pulvinar. Suspendisse accumsan interdum odio. Suspendisse egestas elit in metus. Nam faucibus. Aenean dictum. Nunc libero. Fusce tempus, sagittis sollicitudin, ultricies et, lacinia quis, diam. Vestibulum id nibh
            sed turpis laoreet blandit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris consequat. Quisque leo erat, egestas quis, pellentesque eu, suscipit sit amet, sem. Proin dapibus enim id nibh.
            Fusce diam. Duis sagittis erat eget est. Nam pulvinar egestas elit. Quisque turpis nisl, ornare eu, ultrices eu, sodales sit amet, neque. Quisque id dui non mauris congue venenatis. Praesent cursus, ipsum sed hendrerit sollicitudin, lacus
            orci gravida orci, nec convallis tellus ligula vulputate risus. Phasellus arcu. Sed commodo sapien rutrum nulla. Donec dictum lectus vel purus. Cras massa nisi, ultrices nec, bibendum eu, mollis in, nibh. Fusce tempus, elit non egestas mattis,
            ligula neque tincidunt nisl, in aliquam neque dui ut diam. Pellentesque aliquam fermentum leo. Proin placerat sollicitudin nisi. Sed at diam eu nisl feugiat tempor. sed condimentum tellus tortor ut mi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
            senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Fusce aliquet. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per .</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="parent">

    <div class="apvr-presentation-panel-wrap" id="panel2">
      <div class="apvr-presentation-panel">
        <div class="apvr-presentation-content-wrap">
          <div class="apvr-presentation-content">
            <p class="apvr-presentation-title">Class aptent</p>
            <p class="apvr-presentation-desc">Mauris et sapien. Quisque risus. Ut laoreet hendrerit mi. Nam vestibulum viverra diam. Nullam eros ipsum, rutrum ut, ultricies sed, congue sed, est. Pellentesque porttitor.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: `height: 100%` means that it will have 100% of the parent height. However, the default height is `fit-content` which means the height is **undefined** and will be calculated to fit the content. `100%` of undefined is still undefined. So you need to set at least a specific `max-height` in an absolute or semi-absolute unit such as `px`, `em` or `rem`

Comment: On which element should I add max-height?